# Create an IP camera from a virtual camera (ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, camera, v4l2

We need to use an IP camera for streaming. First of all, I created a virtual camera from a usb cam using v4l2loopback with these two commands:

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=5 card_label="Virtual Camera" exclusive caps=1
```

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video2 -f v4l2 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p /dev/video5
```

Then, I tried to run this command but it didn't work.

```
mjpg_streamer -i "input_uvc.so -r 1280x720 -d /dev/video5 -f 30" -o "output_http.so -p 8080 -w /usr/local/share/mjpg-streamer/www"
```

the output was as follows:

```
i: Using V4L2 device.: /dev/video2
 i: Desired Resolution: 1280 x 720
 i: Frames Per Second.: 30
 i: Format............: JPEG
 i: TV-Norm...........: DEFAULT
Unable to set format: 1196444237 res: 1280x720
Init v4L2 failed !! exit fatal
 i: init_VideoIn failed
```

Comment: What do you consider to be "IP camera"? I recommend using RTSP protocol, but it's unclear if that is what you are looking for.